# Scroll is not smooth when showing long text post in Label cells using CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

i am making app with CollectionView cells using Swift and i fetching posts from my WordPress Website, i want to show posts in CollectionView cell and i want to show full text in Label, but the problem is that when is show posts on CollectionView , scroll is not smooth and sometimes it just stop scrolling for some seconds, this is my code to fetch posts..

```
 func fetchPostData(completionHandler: @escaping ([Post]) -> Void ) {
   
   
      let url = URL(string: "https://www.sikhnama.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?categories=5&per_page=30&page=\(page)\(sortBy)")!
      
      let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
          
          guard let data = data else {return}
          
          do {
              
              let postsData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data)
              
              completionHandler(postsData)
              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  self.collectionView.reloadData()
                  SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                  
              }
          }
          
          catch {
              
              let error = error
              print(String(describing: error))
          }
          
          
          
      }
    task.resume()
      
      
      
      
      
      
  }
```

this is in my CollectionViewCell

```
 override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
   setNeedsLayout()
   layoutIfNeeded()
   let size = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(layoutAttributes.size)
   var frame = layoutAttributes.frame
   frame.size.height = ceil(size.height)
   layoutAttributes.frame = frame
   return layoutAttributes
```

}

and this is how i convert html to text

```
titleLabel.text = String(htmlEncodedString: hukam.content.rendered)
```

this is in Viewdid load

```
 let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
            layout.itemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
            layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width-20, height: 40)
```

this is collectionView Extension

```
extension StatusViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return newsData.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    
       
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "postcell", for: indexPath) as! StatusViewCell
        
     
        
        cell.setup(with: newsData[indexPath.row])
        
    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
      
        
        return cell
    
    
    
    
    
}
```

and this is how i setup constrain of label

[image]

this is my cpu profiler in Instruments

[image]

this is how i convert html to text

```
    extension String {
    init(htmlEncodedString: String) {
        self.init()
        guard let encodedData = htmlEncodedString.data(using: .utf8) else {
            self = htmlEncodedString
            return
        }
        
        let attributedOptions: [String : Any] = [
            convertFromNSAttributedStringDocumentAttributeKey(NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey.documentType): convertFromNSAttributedStringDocumentType(NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html),
            convertFromNSAttributedStringDocumentAttributeKey(NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey.characterEncoding): String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
        ]
        
        do {
            let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: convertToNSAttributedStringDocumentReadingOptionKeyDictionary(attributedOptions), documentAttributes: nil)
            self = attributedString.string
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
            self = htmlEncodedString
        }
    }
}


fileprivate func convertFromNSAttributedStringDocumentAttributeKey(_ input: NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey) -> String {
    return input.rawValue
}


fileprivate func convertFromNSAttributedStringDocumentType(_ input: NSAttributedString.DocumentType) -> String {
    return input.rawValue
}




fileprivate func convertToNSAttributedStringDocumentReadingOptionKeyDictionary(_ input: [String: Any]) -> [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey: Any] {
    return Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: input.map { key, value in (NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey(rawValue: key), value)})
}
```

Comment: How and when do you do fetch data ? This could be due to main thread somehow waiting for your data to be finish fetching but can't confirm if this is the exact case without looking at more code.

Comment: if i use only images or excerpt in posts thats working fine , but for long text in Label not working smoothly @Gihan

Comment: Use the CPU profiler in Instruments to tell you what operation  is expensive during scrolling. I suspect html to text might be blocking the main thread.

Comment: @WarrenBurton i have added screenshot of cpu profiler please look, i also think html to text is the main culprit here , please help

Comment: @noorapps - you need to provide more details. What "html" are you getting that you're converting to a string?

Comment: @DonMag this is the html content i print in Xcode

<p>A soldier ran up to a nun. Out of breath he asked, “Please, may I hide under your skirt, I&#8217;ll explain later.”</p>
<p>The nun agreed. A moment later two military police ran up and asked, “Sister, have you seen a soldier?”</p>
<p>The nun replied, “He went that way.”</p>
<p>After the military police ran off, the soldier crawled out from under her skirt and said, “I can&#8217;t thank you enough Sister. You see, I don&#8217;t want to go to Ukraine.” The nun said, “I understand completely.” The soldier added, “I hope I&#8217”</p>

Comment: i have updated question with the code how i convert html , please see @DonMag

Comment: @noorapps - OK... to find out what's "slow," change this line: `titleLabel.text = String(htmlEncodedString: hukam.content.rendered)` to this: `titleLabel.text = hukam.content.rendered` -- so you're **not** doing the convert to-from html. You will see all of the tags (`<p>` etc), but if the scrolling is still not smooth then you need to look for a problem elsewhere. If the scrolling **does** become smooth, then let's try a more efficient conversion.

Comment: sir i got the main problem but don't know how to solve and i don't know if anyone has faced it . my main language in this app is my regional language and when i use my local language in label then i see the problem but when i use english status , scrolling is smooth, i don't know the main reason behind it, can you help ? thanks @DonMag

Comment: @noorapps - put together a [mre] and post it somewhere like GitHub and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @DonMag i have uploaded on GitHub , here is the link https://github.com/chandninder/scrollproblem.git 

please take a look , thanks

Comment: @noorapps - OK... couple problems. First, because the text is all unicode chars, `UILabel` is very slow to render. Doing some quick experimenting, `WKWebView` renders it ***much*** faster - so you will likely be better off using a web view instead of a label. However, there are problems with the way you were attempting to use the web view. I'm playing around with a few things to see if I can get it to a satisfactory result.

Comment: @noorapps - couple issues... 1. the complex unicode characters take a long time to render in a `UILabel` 2. they render much quicker in a `WKWebView`, but `.loadHTMLString(...)` is an async process, so you don't know the content height until after the cell has been displayed. Options: show only 2 or 3 lines, with a "see more" button... pre-calculate the content heights (slow, and may be very awkward if you're retrieving "sets of posts" while scrolling)... tell the collection view (or table view) to re-layout the cells as the content is rendered (slow and not very smooth)...

Comment: how can i add see more button ? i dont know about it ,

Comment: The culprit might be `NSAttributedString(data:options:documentAttributes:)` since it's slow, and needs to be done in main thread. To verify it: `titleLabel.text = String(htmlEncodedString: hukam.content.rendered)` -> `titleLabel.text = hukam.content.rendered`, if then it's not laggy anymore, you get the real culprit. Depending on what the HTML tags are (only `</p>`, etc, a "replace", regex, etc) might be quicker.

Comment: @Larme thats slow too, already checked it

Comment: @noorapps - unless you have a compelling reason to use collection view, I **strongly** recommend using a `UITableView` instead. Head over to Google (or your favorite search engine) and search for `swift uitableviewcell show more`

Comment: @Larme - the problem is not with html conversion... it is directly related to `UILabel` being slow to render high-Unicode strings. I put up a demo here: https://gist.github.com/DonMag/784a81668916ebdbbd5d7844ec09212c

Answer (score 0):

I made a new application using tableView, there were cuts at the end of the descriptions of the news in my application, so I chose the label from the main Storyboard menu and made Autoshirink as Minimum font scale, I reduced it by 0.5 and it worked.
don't forget to make the lines zero because zero means you have infinite lines

[image]

Comment: how do you convert html to text in label ? do you use label as a full content post or just excerpt ?

Comment: I got the data as JSON. It might be easier to get the data as JSON, parse it and display it in the collectionView

Comment: yes i mean i got this problem when i get the data as full post of Wordpress but when there is no tags like <br> <p> etc , scroll is smooth, thats why i am asking how do you show json data into label ? can you please share screenshot or code ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I parsed the data from JSON. I created a model, I put that model in an empty array here, then I added the data I parsed into my array, then when I show it in the cell, I print it according to the indexPath.row of this array.

```
func fetchNews(){
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://inshorts.deta.dev/news?category="+categoryId)!)
        loading.startAnimating()
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
            do{
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [String : AnyObject]
                if let articklesFromJson = json["data"] as? [[String : AnyObject]]{
                    for articleFromJson in articklesFromJson {
                        let article = NewsModel()
                        if let title = articleFromJson["title"] as? String, let author = articleFromJson["author"] as? String, let content = articleFromJson["content"] as? String, let imageUrl = articleFromJson["imageUrl"] as? String {
                            article.author = author
                            article.content = content
                            article.title = title
                            article.imageUrl = imageUrl
                        }
                        self.News?.append(article)
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
        }catch {
            print("error")
        }
        }
        task.resume()
       
    }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! tableCell
    cell.titleCell.text = self.News?[indexPath.item].title
    cell.authorCell.text = self.News?[indexPath.item].author
    cell.textCell.text = self.News?[indexPath.item].content
    cell.imgCell.dowloadImage(from: (self.News![indexPath.item].imageUrl!))
    loading.stopAnimating()
    return cell
}
```

Comment: i don't know what is error for me , when i load simple text no problem but when i use html in label then the problem occured, only when the length of the text is big..

Comment: I hope you can fix your error

Comment: This shouldn't fix the issue. It's just parsing, and in recent Swift, it's recommended to use `Codable` and `JSONDecoder` instead o `JSONSerialization`.

Comment: Yes, I know, I shared it because a friend asked me how to parse it and asked me for a piece of code.